# Effect on $R^2$ squared of an additional regressor

Tags: linear-regression

I'm currently dealing with the simple linear regression model and the book I'm studying with says that, any time you add a regressor to your model, even if irrelevant, the coefficient of determination

$$R^2 = \frac{ESS}{TSS}$$

Increases necessarily. Why is that the case?

Thanks in advance, peace.

Comment: Also here is an intuitive reason why we would expect this: recall that $R^2$ measures "the proportion of variation in the data that is explained by the model". If you add in a regressor, you're still keeping the old ones, so you're explaining at least as much by having one more. So the $R^2$ should go up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to write $R^2$ is
$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{\text{RSS}}{\text{TSS}}$$
where
$$\text{RSS} = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{\beta}^\top x_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \sum_{j=1}^d \hat{\beta}_j (x_i)_j)^2$$
is the *residual sum of squares*, which is the sum of the squares of the errors of your least squares fit $\hat{\beta}$.

If we show that adding a regressor necessarily decreases [or stays the same], then $R^2$ necessarily increases [or stays the same].

The idea is that $\hat{\beta}$ is *defined* to minimize the RSS. That is,
$$\text{RSS} = \min_\beta \sum_i (y_i - \sum_{j=1}^d \beta_j (x_i)_j)^2.$$
If we add another regressor, then you would instead solve the problem
$$\min_\beta \sum_i \left[y_i - (\beta_{d+1} (x_i)_{d+1} + \sum_{j=1}^d \beta_j (x_i)_j)\right]^2.$$
This value is necessarily smaller than the previous one because if you add the restriction $\beta_{d+1}= 0$ you obtain the original problem; thus adding a regressor ($\beta_{d+1} \ne 0$) can only help you find something smaller.